# FOR loop in batch file question

Tags: batch-file

For the first time ever, im trying to write a simple batch file  for-loop.

Here is my (pseudo) code.

```
FOR /f %%f IN ("alpha","bravo","charlie") DO  echo %%f
```

The intended output is for it to run the command for each word in the brackets (i.e. seperated by a comma).

```
alpha
bravo
charlie
```

It currently just prints `alpha"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove /f so this is

```
FOR %%f IN ("alpha","bravo","charlie") DO  echo %%f
```

edited answer to remove the separated by spaces as I wasn't aware that you can use either space or commas to separate element of list.

Comment: Thanks, it was the /f at the beginning breaking it.

Comment: If you want to keep the wheel spinning, don't forget to accept answers.

Comment: @maxp: you STILL haven't received Eric's answer... please do it!!